# PHP md5 conversion to Coldfusion for CloudTrax

Tags: php, coldfusion

I am converting the php sample code for CloudTrax (it's a wifi access point) to ColdFusion. I having an issue with a line of code. Two data types are concatenated. I have tried multiple times but cannot get it to work. I am not sure what php is doing internally, or if it is converting the data internally to make it work.

$hexchall <- binary

$secret <- string

**PHP**

```
$crypt_secret = md5($hexchall . $secret, TRUE)
```

**CFM**

```
binaryDecode(lcase(hash(hexchall&secret,"MD5")),"hex")
```

Coldfusion responds: *ByteArray objects cannot be converted to strings.*
If I use `CharsetEncode()` on the binary, it no longer matches the output of php.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a php guy, but I am pretty sure you cannot just concatenate the two variables on the CF side. Not unless both values share the same encoding.  Instead, try decoding both values into binary, merging them, then hashing the merged array. I suspect that is what PHP is doing internally.

The exact code will vary depending on the encoding of your strings, but something like this should work in CF10+.

**CF:**

```
// decode both values into binary 
hexchall = binaryDecode("546869732069732062696e617279", "hex");
secret = charsetDecode("this is a secret", "utf-8");
// merge the binary into a single array
// note: arrayAppend will not work with these values
util = createObject("java", "org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils");
mergedBytes = util.addAll(hexchall, secret);
// finally, hash the binary
crypt_secret = lcase(hash( mergedBytes, "md5"));
writeDump(crypt_secret);
```

**PHP:**

```
$hexchall = hex2Bin("546869732069732062696e617279"); 
$secret = "this is a secret";
$crypt_secret = md5($hexchall. $secret, TRUE);
print_r(bin2hex($crypt_secret));
```

**Result:**

```
2e7840389862afdc913c51df5f394125
```